# Error in PHP file uploader

Tags: php

Now, i am getting another problem.... i am trying to upload file with this code :-

```
<form action="up.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
                    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!"/>
</form>
```

Here is the up.php:-

```
if(!isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"])) die("Hacking attempt");
```

In the above code, it says Hacking attempt... why isnt it having the file??

Comment: try var_dump($q) and let me know the result, I guess the result is bool(false), if so, maybe you have enter the wrong connection information

Comment: Could you output `mysql_error($q)`? This should give you enough information about what might be wrong.

Comment: yes... it says bool(false)... why does it say that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start mysql_ functions are deprecated - use mysqli_ or PDO
But try the following to identify the error:

```
$q = mysql_query($query,$c);
if (!$q) die(mysql_error());`
```

Comment: Thanks all... i found my problem... it said table didnt exist. The table i created was wrongly made... thanks all a LOT :D

Comment: @Ed Heal: Please let me know , Is that mysql procedure?

Comment: @usernaveen - Why not Google it?

Comment: @EdHeal: Thank you , I got it, it  is PHP mysql query!